# Tiny Linked List error in C

Tags: c, gcc

I have this four files,

tinyll.c tinyll.h in /home/user/lib

test.c tinyll.h in /home/user/code

and compile with this instructions for create a static library
libtinyll.a and use it.

```
; in lib
$ gcc -c tinyll.c
$ ar -cvq libtinyll.a *.o

; in code
$ gcc -o test test.c ../lib/libtinyll.a
```

Until here all is ok. But I don't know why I obtain segmentation fault because the lines from [CODE ERROR] but showElements work. The target is not pass code from test.c to tinyll.c for treat the tiny list linked. How fix that?

```
/////////////////////////////////// test.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "tinyll.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    progname = argv[0];

    char *file = "fwords";
    int n;
    PTLL lsone = NULL;
    n = loadfileinTLL(file,&lsone);

    // work. good. 
    showElements(lsone);

    // [CODE ERROR]
    // Why here dont work?
    // segmentation fault, load the first word
    // but in the second crash.
    while (lsone != NULL) {
        printf("%s",lsone->word);
        lsone = lsone->next;
    }    
    return 0;
}

/////////////////////////////////// tinyll.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "tinyll.h"

void addElement(PPTLL lst, char data[])
{
    PTLL elemt;
    elemt = (PTLL) malloc(sizeof(TLL));

    if (elemt == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: insufficient memory.\n", progname);
        exit(1);    
    }

    if (*lst == NULL)
    {
        strncpy(elemt->word, data, 45);
        elemt->next = NULL;
        *lst = elemt;
    }
    else {
        // add in front of list
        strncpy(elemt->word, data, 45);
        elemt->next = *lst;
        *lst = elemt;
    }
}

void showElements(PTLL lst)
{
    while (lst != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n",lst->word);
        lst = lst->next;
    }
}

int loadfileinTLL(char *filepath, PPTLL plst) 
{
    FILE *f;
    if ((f = fopen(filepath, "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: error to load file %s.\n", progname, filepath);
        exit(1);
    }

    char buf[45]; int n=0;
    while (fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),f) != NULL) {
        char *nl;
        if ((nl = strchr(buf,'\n')) != NULL) {
            *nl = '\0';
        }
        addElement(plst,buf);
        n++;
    }

    fclose(f);

    return n;
}

//////////////////////////////////// tinyll.h

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifndef _TINYLL_
#define _TINYLL_

struct list {
    char word[45];
    struct list *next;
};

// Tiny Linked List
typedef struct list TLL;
typedef struct list *PTLL;
typedef struct list **PPTLL;
char *progname;

#endif
```

Comment: Run the code in a debugger (ex. `gdb`). It should stop where the program segfaults. You can then obtain where the code crashed, using the backtrace (`bt`) command, and inspect variables with `print (some expression)`

Comment: You might want to use [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

Comment: You want to make another pointer to step down the linked list. If you use your handle on the linked list to traverse (i.e.: `lsone`), then you will have memory leaks

Comment: Could it be the `word` is longer than supposed?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors when I compile this - even when I use a long word (seems to be a buffer overflow, but you're using fgets, so I think you're safe there).  You're definitely leaking memory though - you never free the elements you allocate (valgrind confirms this).

Comment: Also you have two global variables named progname ... not one as intended.

Comment: Debugger, debugger.....

Comment: Are you sure the segfault is after the first word? stdout is line buffered, so unless your words contain newline characters that printf isn't suited for debugging.

Comment: in the tinyll.h file, the variable: 'char *progname;' is being defined.  This means a separate variable in each .c source file that includes the tinyll.h header file.   Strongly suggest: place the 'char *progname;' declaration in a single file, perhaps the file that contains the main() function, as global variable.   Then in the tinyll.h file use 'extern char *progname;'

Comment: there is no need to #include the stdio.h and stdlib.h header files in the tinyll.h header file.

Comment: in C, when calling the system function: malloc() (and family of functions) do no cast the returned value.  Because the returned value is a 'void*' so can be assigned to any pointer.

Comment: when error checking, after calling a system function, use 'perror()' as that displays both the incorporated text and the system error message (as selected by errno) which will have the real reason the system function failed.

Comment: prototypes for the functions in tinyll.c are not available to test.c.  Suggest placing those prototypes in the tinyll.h file

Comment: Thanks everybody for reply and leave your recommendations, I can fix the error add a new pointer to lsone in main() PTLL ls = lsone; and work with this. The Broffesor had reason. But now I get something curious, with showElements this show all elements, but in main with ls .. I get the last element. *lst = elemt; should place me in the front of the list.

Comment: @tonysdg, suggest compiling with all warnings enabled.  then you will see lots of warnings about problems in the code.  for gcc, at a minimum, use: '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic'

Answer (score 0):

the following code:

```
1) compiles cleanly
2) performs correctly, with out seg faulting.
3) checks and handles errors correctly
4) cleans up after itself, by freeing any allocated memory
5) removed leading underscores from names 
   as leading underscores has special meaning to the compiler
```

tinyll.h

```
#ifndef TINYLL_
#define TINYLL_

struct list
{
    char word[45];
    struct list *next;
};

// Tiny Linked List
typedef struct list TLL;
typedef struct list *PTLL;
typedef struct list **PPTLL;
extern char *progname;

void addElement(PPTLL lst, char data[]);
void showElements(PTLL lst);
int loadfileinTLL(char *filepath, PPTLL plst);


#endif // TINYLL_
```

tinyll.c

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

 #include "tinyll.h"

void addElement(PPTLL lst, char data[])
{
    PTLL elemt;
    elemt = (PTLL) malloc(sizeof(TLL));

    if (elemt == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: insufficient memory.\n", progname);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (*lst == NULL)
    {
        strncpy(elemt->word, data, 45);
        elemt->next = NULL;
        *lst = elemt;
    }
    else {
        // add in front of list
        strncpy(elemt->word, data, 45);
        elemt->next = *lst;
        *lst = elemt;
    }
}

void showElements(PTLL lst)
{
    while (lst != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n",lst->word);
        lst = lst->next;
    }
}

int loadfileinTLL(char *filepath, PPTLL plst)
{
    int n=0;

    FILE *f;
    if ((f = fopen(filepath, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: error to load file %s.\n", progname, filepath);
        n = -1;
    }

    else
    {
        char buf[45];

        while (fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),f) != NULL)
        {
            char *nl;
            if ((nl = strchr(buf,'\n')) != NULL)
            {
                *nl = '\0';
            }
            addElement(plst,buf);
            n++;
        }

        fclose(f);
    } // endif

    return n;
}
```

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "tinyll.h"

char *progname;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if( 1 == argc )
    {
        progname = argv[0];
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "USAGE: %s\n", argv[0]);
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, right number (0) of arguments on command line

    char *file = "fwords";
    int n;
    PTLL lsone = NULL;
    PTLL lstwo = NULL;

    n = loadfileinTLL(file,&lsone);

    if( n > 0 )
    {

        // work. good.
        showElements(lsone);

        // [CODE ERROR]
        // Why here dont work?
        // segmentation fault, load the first word
        // but in the second crash.
        lstwo = lsone;
        while (lstwo)
        {
            printf("%s",lstwo->word);
            lstwo = lstwo->next;
        }
    } // endif

    while( lsone )
    {
        lstwo = lsone->next;
        free(lsone);
        lsone = lstwo;
    } // end while

    return 0;
}
```

I used the following for a test file:

```
one
two
three
four
five
six
```

and the output was:

```
six
five
four
three
two
one
sixfivefourthreetwoone
```

Comment: if the posted code had been compiled with all warnings enabled (for gcc, at a minimum use: '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic')  Then many/most of the errors in the code would have been revealed.  in general, always fix (not hide) all warnings.  Afterall, the compiler knows the language much better than us humans know the language.

Comment: BTW: gcc has the PIC and static parameters available for creating static libraries as a third step.   it is best to compile as step one, then step 2 is either create a library or link object files and libraries into an executable